# Xcode Swift target overrides the `SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS`

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I just switched from Carthage to Cocapods for an older Swift project.  When I run "pod install", I get a warning (one for Debug and one for Release):

*[!] The 'POS Pad [Debug]' target overrides the `SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-POS Pad/Pods-POS Pad.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation*

The problem is that I cannot find any "Swift Include Paths" setting anywhere under Build Settings.  I am using Xcode 13.4.

Where can I find this setting and get rid of the warnings?

Answer (score 1):

I took another stab at this and found a way to get rid of the warnings.

When looking at the project.pbxproj file directly, the setting SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS was actually present under release and debug.  However, both were set to "$(default)", so they were not overriden like Cocoapods claimed they were.

To handle:

1. Edit the project.pbxproj file and delete the two lines (after making a copy of the file to be safe).
2. pod deintegrate
3. Delete derived data (rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*)
4. In Xcode, Clean Build Folder

After the above, pod install ran without warnings or errors.

Note: step 2-4 above might not have been needed.

Hopefully this helps somebody if they have a similar issue...